# Issue running pyspark on Mac

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, homebrew

I've been trying to install and use Apache Spark and pyspark on my Mac, by following [this tutorial](https://maelfabien.github.io/bigdata/SparkInstall/).

Running `pyspark` in the terminal appears to load everything correctly, as it displays the `SparkSession available as 'spark'` message. However, when I load a Jupyter Notebook with pyspark installed and attempt to run this below code,

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

I get the following message:
`Couldn't find Spark, make sure SPARK_HOME env is set or Spark is in an expected location (e.g. from homebrew installation).`

How can I resolve this issue?

Massive thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: Where is Spark installed?  What is the value of `$SPARK_HOME`?

Comment: @0x5453 When I try executing `echo $SPARK_HOME`, it returns completely empty

Comment: You may need to restart your shell.  But if `$SPARK_HOME` is still empty after that, it would seem you didn't follow the tutorial correctly (namely step 6).

Comment: did you source your bashrc?

Comment: @0x5453 @yayati-sule For anyone in the future, I managed to sort this by opening the .zshrc file manually and adding the appropriate paths for `JAVA_HOME`, `JRE_HOME`, `PATH`, `SPARK_HOME` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON`.